# How to achive that zooming effect?

Tags: html, css, hover, effect

I would like to ask how can I achieve a hovering effect just like this one here ? I mean the one when you hover an image.
[Link to a page with desired effect](https://icreeative.github.io/weeklywebdev/30/#project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following property :

```
.item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(2.0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(2.0);
  transform: scale(2.0);
}
```

This will make a zoom in effect on the image when it is hovered on.
You can vary the parameters for achieving the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this, its similar to what you want:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
p {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    line-height: 100px;
}
img:hover {
-moz-transform: scale(2.0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(2.0);
  transform: scale(2.0);
}
img {
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok,that's great :D And how can i add a text ? For example "lorem ipsum" on hovered part ? Just like on this page :)

Comment: @Atomix updated the code for text